# splicing Image with wand, python doesn't work

Tags: python, image, wand

So I want to splice an image into two, for which I wrote this code.

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
with Image(filename="test.png") as im :
  im.trim(color=None,fuzz=0)
  x,y = im.size
  xh,yh = int(x/2),int(y/2)
  print(x,y,xh,yh)
  im1 = im[0:xh,0:y]
  print(im1.size)
  display(im1)
```

The size of image is (1156,242) and hence the spliced image should be (578,242), but it's (553,235) instead. Anyone knows why? [Here is the test image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WToKS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the effect of using `wand.image.Image.trim`. A simple "repage" is all that's needed.

```py
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="test.png") as im :
  im.trim(color=None,fuzz=0)
  im.reset_coords()  # <= Same as `-repage'
  x,y = im.size
  xh,yh = int(x/2),int(y/2)
  print(x,y,xh,yh)
  im1 = im[0:xh,0:y]
  print(im1.size)
  display(im1)
```

I don't have the doc links handy at the moment, but a quick search for ImageMagick's `-repage` command line option should help describe the process.

Comment: This Worked. Thanks.